# Implement a cake baking state machine in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, state-machine

Once again, I cannot wrap my head around this piece of cake:

```
data Event = AddEggs | AddFlour | AddSugar | Mix | Bake
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

The cake baking states are as of now:

```
data State = Start | Error | Finished | HasEggs | HasFlour | HasSugar | HasFlourAndSugar | Mixed 
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

The state machine starts at state `Start` and it halts in either `Error` or `Finished`.

Two valid state sequences are:

1. `[AddEggs, AddFlour, AddSugar, Mix, Bake]`
2. `[AddEggs, AddSugar, AddFlour, Mix, Bake]`

Note above that `AddFlour` and `AddSugar` can appear in two different orders. Also, after `Bake`, you can add more events and the state machine remains in either `Finished` or `Error`. Finally, if the state order is broken, it goes to the `Error` state, and no event can "save" it.

**My best attempt**

```
data Event = AddEggs | AddFlour | AddSugar | Mix | Bake
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data State = Start | Error | Finished | HasEggs | HasFlour | HasSugar | HasFlourAndSugar | Mixed 
  deriving (Eq, Show)

stepHelper :: State -> Event -> Bool -> Bool -> State

stepHelper Start AddEggs False False = HasEggs
stepHelper Start AddEggs True _ = Error
stepHelper Start AddEggs _ True = Error
stepHelper Start _ _ _ = Error

stepHelper HasEggs AddFlour has_flour has_sugar = if has_flour then Error else HasFlour
stepHelper HasEggs AddSugar has_flour has_sugar = if has_sugar then Error else HasSugar

stepHelper HasEggs AddFlour _ has_sugar = stepHelper HasEggs AddFlour True has_sugar
stepHelper HasEggs AddSugar has_flour _ = stepHelper HasEggs AddSugar has_flour True
stepHelper _ Mix has_flour has_sugar = if has_flour && has_sugar then Mixed else Error
stepHelper Mixed Bake _ _ = Finished

step :: State -> Event -> State
step s e = stepHelper s e False False

-- do not edit this
bake :: [Event] -> State
bake events = go Start events
  where go state [] = state
        go state (e:es) = go (step state e) es
```

**Running my MWE**

1. Clone [this repo](https://github.com/coderodde/my-haskell-mooc)
2. In `my-haskell-mooc` `cd` to `exercises`
3. Run `stack runhaskell Set7Test.hs`

**The error message**

After above 3 steps, I get:

```
Set7.hs:61:1: warning: [-Wtabs]
    Tab character found here, and in 29 further locations.
    Please use spaces instead.
   |
61 |         ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | ^^^^^^^^

Set7.hs:119:29: error: parse error on input `='
    |
119 |             go state (e:es) = go (step state e) es
```

Comment: What does not work? What is your question?

Comment: I don't get the point of the two booleans in the `stepHelper` function. Can you explain what you were trying to achieve with them?

Comment: @Bergi The  aforementioned `Set7Test.hs` does not pass the task presented in this post. I thought that keeping two booleans for sugar/flour would cut it just nice.

Comment: The errors you've posted are compiler warnings and errors. It usually pays to heed even warnings, since compiler warnings earlier in a file may have cascading effects that cause the final error further down. While this may not be the case here, make it a habit to address all compiler warnings first, in order to rule out that they may be the root cause.

Comment: Of course, if you need help understanding a compiler warning, you're welcome to ask a question here on Stack Overflow. The current warning, however, quite explicitly tells you what the problem is, so you can probably figure that one out on your own.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler warning is a herald of the error that comes later. You are mixing spaces and tabs, and you have done it wrong. Indentation and aligntment matters in Haskell. Look in your Github repo and see how the function in question renders:

```
-- do not edit this
bake :: [Event] -> State
bake events = go Start events
  where go state [] = state
            go state (e:es) = go (step state e) es
```

If you don't edit that, I promise it will never compile. It needs to align.

It looks like in [2c9877caf](https://github.com/coderodde/my-haskell-mooc/commit/2c9877cafdaac1838e239c896ce7045856013977) you added tabs to a bunch of lines. Most of them are harmless because they are inside comments, but your life will be easier if you just never insert a tab character into a source file.

Answer (score 0):

Your state transition function should only take two arguments: the current state and the action. A single state should carry *all* the information about what you've done so far. You have five actions that can affect the state, which means you have at least 32 different states. Since some sequences of actions are clearly invalid (you can't bake before adding all the ingredients), which lets you collapse many of those states into the `Error` state. For example, there's no need for a state represented a baked but unmixed set of ingredients. But things like `HasEggsAndFlour` and `HasEggs` (lack of flour implied) are two different states.

```
data Event = AddEggs | AddFlour | AddSugar | Mix | Bake
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Instead of enumerating your states immediately, start defining your step function to see what states you'll need to define. For example,

```
step :: State -> Event -> State
step Error _ = Error -- Can't recover from an error
step Finished _ = Error  -- Not clear what you can do with a finished cake
-- You can start a cake by adding any one ingredient
step Start AddEggs = HasEggs
step Start AddFlour = HasFlour
step Start AddSugar = HasSugar
step Start _ = Error -- Cannot yet mix or bake
-- Once there are eggs, there are only two more ingredients you can add
step HasEggs AddFlour = HasEggsAndFlour
step HasEggs AddSugar = HasEggsAndSugar
step HasEggs _ = Error  -- Can't mix, bake, or add more eggs
...
step HasEggsSugarFlour Mix = ReadyToBake
step HasEggsSugarFlour _ = Error  -- can't add anything else, can't bake yet
step ReadyToBake Bake = Finished -- can't do anything except bake
step ReadyToBake _ = Error
step Error _ = Error
```

How you define the states can vary. Above, I'm implying separate nullary constructors for each state. You can break it down into simpler boolean-like states (to avoid boolean blindness) that can be combined. For example,

```
data Egged = HasEggs | HasNoEggs
data Floured = HasFlour | HasNoFlour
data Sugared = HasSugar | HasNoSugar
data Mixed = Mixed | Unmixed
data Baked = Baked | Unbaked

data State = Start | Finished | Error | InProgress Egged Floured Sugared Mixed

step :: State -> Event -> State
step Error _ = Error
step Finished _ = Error
-- When can and can't we add eggs:
step Start AddEggs = InProgress HasEggs HasNoFlour HasNoSugar Unmixed
step (InProgress HasNoEggs flour sugar Unmixed Unbaked) AddEggs = InProgress HasEggs flour sugar Unmixed
step (InProgress HasEggs _ _ _ _) = Error
-- When can and can't we add sugar
...
-- When can we bake
step (InProgress HasEggs HasFlour HasSugar Mixed Unbaked) Bake = Finished
step _ Bake = Error
```

Comment: I think OP already defined their states correctly, but `HasFlour | HasSugar | HasFlourAndSugar` implicitly imply `…AndEggs` as they always come after the `AddEggs` event

Comment: It's the implicit state definitions I don't like. One could make a mistake in defining `step` and suddenly the semantics of `HasFlour` could change. (I should note, I answered the question thinking the problem was in understanding the code, in particular not understanding where such state constraints were made implicitly. My answer was intended to separate the semantics of a single state from the definition of transitions involving the state.)